# Python time function

Tags: python, subprocess

I have code shown below:

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        while p.poll() is None:
                print "Loading mWorker... please wait"
                time.sleep(2)

        return p.communicate()
```

I originally thought the p.communicate() should be prior to the while statement. However I find that this function call will hang (e.g. I do not see anything past the return prompt) if it is not placed at the end of the method. If I run the method as shown above, I will only get 1 print statement and then

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "python.py", line 10, in run_command
    time.sleep(2)
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

Why am I seeing this? Why doesn't time work more than once? And what changes do I need to make so I will continue to see the print statement?

Comment: Time doesn't work even once ... You print the stuff then you hit the line with `time.sleep`, but python doesn't know what `time` is since you've never imported it.

Comment: the code is broken even with `import time`. Drop the `while`. `p.communicate()` along is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not imported the time module.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't import the time module:

```
import subprocess
import time
...
#rest of your code
```

EDIT:

The fact that you see the print `"Loading mWorker... please wait"` message once doesn't mean it's working. Python will execute commands as it comes to them, in this case it knows how to print, but `time` is undefined so it will print then die on the `time.sleep(2)`. 
   You can prove it to yourself, reverse those two statements and you won't even see the print anymore.